# I have a nice Chinese silk? Painting - any info, price, year, meaning?

Tags: translation

Can someone please help tell me anything about this?

https://imgur.com/a/moXIY2g

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[庚申](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%9A%E7%94%B3) (most likely 1980, or maybe 1920)

花朝俊 Hua Chaojun (artist's name)

為 (for)

蘭泉學兄 - Senior schoolmate Lanquan

大雅之房 - Elegant home

弟 - Your Junior

張丑 - Zhang Chou

The seal said: [吳郡](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E5%90%B4%E9%83%A1)張丑 (Zhang Chou of Wujun)

Notes:

- 學兄 is a respectful address to (1).a senior schoolmate or (2). a respectful address to a person whom you consider to be superior to yourself in academic achievement
- 弟(your junior) is a humble self-address for "I"

My guess is:

In 1980, Zhang Chou from Wujun commissioned the artist Hua Chaojun to paint the screen (屏風) as a gift to his senior schoolmate  Lanquan to celebrate  Lanquan's new home